# Creating a jar file in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a jar file with my own classes.

Can anyone give me sample code for creating a simple jar file in Android?

Comment: ou wan to do it via pro. or in eclipse?

Comment: i don't want import a jar file into my app.I want to create a new jar file contains different classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Creating a JAR File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)
You will get the `.class` file in the bin folder

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it via Eclipse, it's easy.

Go to `File:->Export`. Then choose jar file in jar folder than simply choose proper app and than settings for it so you can export it easily.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy.

Do what Make a folder on to the desktop say MyFolder.

In that folder place the main package of your .class files or directly the class file if they belong to no package.

Say my.main.package is the package that have your classes.

Now the folder MyFolder has one folder by name my in it. Now open the console window and take it to MyFolder Location.

Like this `C:\Documents and settings\Rohit\Desktop\MyFolder>`

Write command like below:

`C:\Documents and settings\Rohit\Desktop\MyFolder>jar -cvf MyJar.jar my`

it will create a jar of your classes that you can import through Eclipse.

and if say you want to make a jar file that will have more then one main package along some class files then write the following command:

`C:\Documents and settings\Rohit\Desktop\MyFolder>jar -cvf MyJar.jar my my2 *.class`

Comment: and yes if it says jar is not found as an internal or external command. that means your java bin class paths are not set .. set it then

Comment: i heared that jar files does not contain Ui statically all are created in one class (Ui also).I don't know How we create the jar file application in android.give me suggestions for crete the jar file application in android

Comment: User333 jars are just used as a archive of classes say helper class. What UI thing you are asking i dont know.. if any of your java class even it create a view doesent matter with jar creation. if you have a group of classes that you want to archive into a jar follow the procedure